# How to tell if Excel Application is in cell-edit mode?

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, com-interop

I'm writing an Excel Addin using COM Interop from .net. I have a command that pops up a dialog, and from the dialog I do some work like collecting data from the used range of several sheets. The problem is that if a cell is in edit mode, some of the calls that I need to make will throw exceptions. I would like a way of determining before-hand that Excel is in edit mode, so that I can warn the user to finish editing the cell first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an Application.Ready property that is supposed to give you this information but in practice it doesn't work reliably. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Excel_Edit_Mode.aspx) for a hackaround.

You might also want to look at setting Application.Interactive=false while your .net code is doing its stuff.

Comment: Confirmed on VSTO 2012 with Excel 2010 -- this workaround also worked for me.   Bummer I had to use this as a hack, but it works better than exceptions showing up in the addin. If anyone knows if they updated or added something new, please update this thread! I hope something has been updated since this thread was first introduced.

Answer (score 5):

Try this function:

```
    Function IsInEditMode(ByRef exapp As Excel.Application) As Boolean
        If exapp.Interactive = False Then
            Return False
        Else
            Try
                exapp.Interactive = False
                exapp.Interactive = True

                Return False
            Catch
                Return True
            End Try
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: This solution is quite old, so I'm not sure if this has always been the case, but in many cases, calling `xlApp.Interactive = false` will cause even more issues. I discovered that in Excel 2013/2016 this line of code will *interrupt* the user if they happen to be performing a number of actions:
- Resizing or moving an excel-owned window (really, any mouse-drag action) - the action will be aborted
- In a non-modal excel-owned dialog like the VBA editor (they will be 'kicked' back to the main workbook  window)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which language you're using. [SZL's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25057820/3626160) is written in VB. Since I'm using  C# I had to convert it. Worked great. Here is the equivalent C# code.

```
    bool IsInEditMode(ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application exapp)
    {
        if (exapp.Interactive == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                exapp.Interactive = false;
                exapp.Interactive = true;
                return false;
            }

            catch
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```