# Workaround to see if Excel is in cell-edit mode in .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, interop, excel-interop

I have an application written in VB.NET that interacts with Excel via interop. 
I eventually ran into the known issue of Cell-edit mode (see [MSDN](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4087801&SiteID=1) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221984/how-to-tell-if-excel-application-is-in-cell-edit-mode) for some background).

I have been trying to convert the suggested code to VB.NET but keep getting the following error:

```
Reference required to assembly 'office, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' containing the type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBars'. Add one to your project. (BC30652) - E:\ ... .vb:3471
```

The original C# code (from previosuly mentioned articles) is as follows

```
private bool IsEditMode()
{
   object m = Type.Missing;
   const int MENU_ITEM_TYPE = 1;
   const int NEW_MENU = 18;

   // Get the "New" menu item.
   CommandBarControl oNewMenu = Application.CommandBars["Worksheet Menu Bar"].FindControl(MENU_ITEM_TYPE, NEW_MENU, m, m, true );

  if ( oNewMenu != null )
  {
     // Check if "New" menu item is enabled or not.
     if ( !oNewMenu.Enabled )
     {
        return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

My converted VB.NET code is as follows

```
Private Function isEditMode() As Boolean
    isEditMode = False
    Dim m As Object = Type.Missing
    Const  MENU_ITEM_TYPE As Integer = 1
    Const  NEW_MENU As Integer = 18

    Dim oNewMenu As Office.CommandBarControl
    ' oExcel is the Excel Application object 
    ' the error is related to the below line
    oNewMenu = oExcel.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").FindControl(MENU_ITEM_TYPE, NEW_MENU, m, m, True)
    If oNewMenu IsNot Nothing Then
        If Not oNewMenu.Enabled Then
            isEditMode = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

I have added a (COM) reference to the Microsoft Office Object Library

```
Imports Office = Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

I am kind of stuck. I already have tried indirectly referencing the CommandBar object, and re-adding refrences but can not figure out what is the problem. any ideas?

Comment: should be 
Imports Office = Microsoft.Office.Core 
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

not

Imports Office = Microsoft.Office.Core 
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick-and-dirty fix i used the following code as an alternative

```
Private Function isEditMode() As Boolean
    isEditMode = False
    Try
        oExcel.GoTo("###")
    Catch Ex As Exception
       ' Either returns "Reference is not valid." 
       ' or "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
       If ex.Message.StartsWith("Exception") then isEditMode  = True
    End Try     
End Function
```

The .GoTo function (and corresponding menu item) is not available when Excel is in Cell-edit mode.
Giving the .GoTo function a dummy destination will do nothing and won't affect anything if the user is working in the cell when the code runs.

An added extra is that no reference to the Microsoft Office Object (Microsoft.Office.Core) library is needed.

Comment: The above has worked fine for a while now on several different setups.

Comment: Did not work well for me. In my case (vb.net with .NET 6.0) the ex.message returns ony "0x800A03EC" so I had to change StartsWith("Exception") to Contains("0x800A03EC")

Answer (score 2):

An older post but not an old problem. The solution above for detect and exit is fine but I found another solution for getting Excel out of edit mode which doesn't need to use an API to find the window or use Sendkeys to click a cell, my solution uses events. Excel can even be in edit mode and minimised and this solution will still work. If you are reading this you probably won't need the exact code but if you do please let me know.
First detect Excel edit mode with a try catch similar to the previous solutions and set a Global flag True if Excel is in edit mode.
Then tell Excel to close. This action will be available even when in edit mode.
In the Excel OnClosing event check if your Global flag is set and if so set the On Closing event 'e.Cancel' to True which will stop Excel closing.
Set your Global flag back to False and when Excel comes back it will be out of edit mode and whatever was written into the edited cell will still be there.

Comment: I posted an example with the exact same principle, and it works like a charm. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76157849/4932683

Answer (score 1):

```
Function ExcelIsBusy()
ExcelIsBusy = Not Application.Ready
Dim m
m = Empty
Const MENU_ITEM_TYPE = 1
Const NEW_MENU = 18

Dim oNewMenu
Set oNewMenu = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").FindControl(MENU_ITEM_TYPE, NEW_MENU, m, m, True)
If Not (oNewMenu Is Nothing) Then
    If Not oNewMenu.Enabled Then
        ExcelIsBusy = True
        'throw new Exception("Excel is in Edit Mode")
    End If
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

We previously used the `Application.CommandBars["Worksheet Menu Bar"]` method but we encountered a flaw. When exiting Excel while in edit mode, edit mode cancels out, but the function still returns true because the menu items have been disabled as part of the shutdown.

We used the following solution instead:

```
public static bool ApplicationIsInEditMode(Application application)
{
    try
    {
        application.ReferenceStyle = application.ReferenceStyle;
    }
    catch (COMException e)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will detect whether excel is in Edit Mode and will exit out of it :

```
private void exitEditMode()
{

    if (!isExcelInteractive())
    {
        // get the current range
        Excel.Range r = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell;
        // bring Excel to the foreground, with focus
        // and issue keys to exit the cell
        xlBringToFront();
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Activate();
        SendKeys.Flush();
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        // now make sure the original cell is
        // selected…
        r.Select();
    }
}

private bool isExcelInteractive()
{
    try
    {
        // this line does nothing if Excel is not
        // in edit mode. However, trying to set
        // this property while Excel is in edit
        // cell mdoe will cause an exception
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive;
        return true; // no exception, ecel is 
        // interactive
    }
    catch
    {
        return false; // in edit mode
    }
}

private void xlBringToFront()
{
    SetForegroundWindow(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd);
}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
```

Comment: the IsExcelInteractive function worked like a charm, but exitEditMode did not work.

Answer (score 0):

### VB.NET code:

```
'Declare Excel object
Public WithEvents Excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Public Function Is_in_edit_mode() As Boolean
    Try
        Excel.Interactive = Excel.Interactive
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Return True
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```