# How can I force a cell to stop editing in Excel interop?

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I have an Excel 2007 add-in with a ribbon. One of the buttons in the ribbon triggers heavy manipulations of the current worksheet and I set various `Excel.Application` properties like `Interactive` and `EnableEvents` to `false` during the manipulations for speed and UX reasons.

My problem is that the ribbon doesn't steal focus so if the user was editing a cell when he clicks my ribbon button, an exception is thrown when setting `Application.Interactive = false` because Excel considers the user is still editing the cell.

Is there a way to stop the edition either by saving or discarding the changes made to the cell?

It appears that `Range.DiscardChanges()` would probably solve my problem but it isn't available in the 2007 API.

EDIT: It seems that `Range.DiscardChanges()` is for ranges based on OLAP data sources so it wouldn't solve my problem anyway.

EDIT: I have tried calling `Range.Activate()` on another cell. While I do see the cell focus changing in the GUI, the exception is thrown anyway. `Range.Select()` doesn't do anything.

Comment: There is a solution near the bottom of this link which may help http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/109032-excel-bug-comsolved/

Comment: @kevchadders This solution uses a third party scripting library in Excel and I'd like a .NET solution. Though it seems like it all boils down to sending and ESC and that didn't work for me with `Application.SendKeys()`. I feel like the Ribbon has the focus at that point in time and the ESC doesn't affect the cell that is in edition.

Comment: In fact, the reason `SendKeys` didn't work is that the ESC takes effect only when the execution is done and the GUI takes control.

Comment: In case you still need a solution, I have found a simple solution using interop event handler in your .NET code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after looking around for a few days and asking on MSDN, the final answer is that there is simply nothing in the API for this and that it isn't possible without using hacky solutions<sup>1</sup>.

The way Excel itself handles this kind of thing is simply to gray out its menus while the user is editing so I've done that instead for the sake of consistency with the host application.

<sup>1</sup>: Hacky, because techniques like using `SendKeys` require going back to the GUI to make sure the action is processed and then calling the method that required the cells to not be in edition. This is fine in one place, but doing that for every method call to the Excel Interop is madness.

Comment: This is not true at present. There is now a simple solution using Interop event handler in .NET code. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can not stop editing but you can check if editing is enabled and afterwards tell the user to stop it:

```
private bool IsEditing(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp)
{
    if (excelApp.Interactive)
    {
        try
        {
            excelApp.Interactive = false;
            excelApp.Interactive = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please stop cell editing before you continue.");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I found the answer at this page and changed it from VBA to C#:
https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/03/23/excel-check-user-edit-cell/

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late to answer to it. But thinking someone use this trick when they look for a solution.

For some reason, the sendkeys and Cells/Range activate command didn't workout.

The only workaround to get rid of this issue would be change the focus to another worksheet and come back to current worksheet to cheat the excel. :-)

```
ExcelUtil.ActivateWorksheet("Sheet1");
currentWorksheet.Activate();

public static void ActivateWorksheet(string strWorksheetName)
    {
        bool found = false;

        foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets)
        {
            if (sheet.Name.ToLower() == strWorksheetName.ToLower())
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
            Globals.ThisAddIn.AddNewWorksheet(strWorksheetName);

        ((Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets[strWorksheetName]).Activate();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Ram

Comment: Except if the cell is being actively edited, the application will not respond to *any* method calls. This needs to be handled with a `try/except`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other proposed solutions worked for me, then I learned that we can use excel Events in the VB.NET application and made a solution using the "BeforeClose" event that forces Excel to exit cell edit mode.

### VB.NET code:

```
'Declare Excel object'
Public WithEvents Excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
public Fake_close as boolean

Public Function Is_in_edit_mode() As Boolean
    Try
        Excel.Interactive = Excel.Interactive
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Return True
    End Try
    Return False
End Function

'Wb = handle to your workbook in Excel'
Public Sub Exit_cell_edit_mode(Wb as Workbook)
    If Not Is_in_edit_mode() Then Exit Sub

    'initiates closing the worksheet, which forces cancellation of cell edit mode.'
    Fake_close = True  'Signal that the closing event is fake'
    Wb.Close()  'This command will trigger the WorkbookBeforeClose event below'
End Sub

'This event will be triggered in the VB.NET app before the workbook is closed on Excel'
Private Sub WorkbookBeforeClose(Wb As Workbook, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Excel.WorkbookBeforeClose
    If Fake_close Then 
        Cancel = True  'Cancel the closing of the workbook'
        Fake_close = False
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not work. Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close() can not be executed because excel is in edit mode.

Comment: Did you test it? I have been using this code for 1 year and it is still working. The Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close() can indeed be executed and it will trigger the WorkbookBeforeClose event that will cancel the closing of the workbook and this exits edit mode. Try it and see

Comment: Yes, I tried it. While in cell edit mode (user types into a cell -> all buttons in the ribbon get disabled --> user clicks out of the excel window and leaves it in cell edit mode), all interop calls will fail. Even Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(). Actually even Excel.ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: Only thing that worked so far was to keep track of all opened window handles and do a User32.PostMessage to the excel windows and send "Enter". Excel will leave the cell edit mode on enter.

Comment: OK I just checked my code and there were some changes that I didn´t update here. You should save the Workbook to a Workbook variable, then use Workbook.Close() instead of Excel.ActiveWorkbook.close(), this should work. I will edit the answer

Answer (score -1):

If you select another cell or all cells, does the error disappear?

`private void myFunction()
     {
         xlSheet.Cells.Select();
         //the rest of the work
     }`

Comment: It doesn't work. `Range.Activate` looked a bit more promising but the exception is thrown anyway. I have added that information to the question.

Comment: Well, an ugly method would be `Application.SendKeys("{ESC}")`. This will send to the application escape key which discards the changes. But I don't think it is a reliable solution.

Comment: Yeah I have already tried that but it didn't work as noted in the question's comments.

Answer (score -1):

I detected the problem and displayed a message to tell user:
         If excelHelper.ExcelIsEditing() Then
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play()
            MsgBox("Please finish editing the sheet!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Move cursor out of current cell and try button again.")
            Exit Function
         End If

Function ExcelIsEditing() As Boolean
      ExcelIsEditing = False

```
  If ExcelApp.Interactive = False Then Return False
  Try
     ExcelApp.Interactive = False
     ExcelApp.Interactive = True
  Catch
     Return True
  End Try
```

End Function

its the best I could come up with :_(