# Python win32com Excel.Application throws error if cursor is in a cell when 'visible' is set to False

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Thanks in advance for your help/advice.

I'm trying to create a program that uses tkinter as a GUI to gather information, then uses win32com to send that information to an existing Excel file. On my Tk window, I have a button which toggles the visibility of the excel file, using the 'visible' attribute of the Com object. It works fine, unless the cursor is still active inside a cell when you attempt to hide the file again (set 'visible' to False). When I do this, it throws an AttributeError. Is there any workaround?

Here is the code I'm using as the command for my button:

```
    def buttonShow(XL):
        XL.visible ^= 1
```

**Edit:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482935/how-can-i-force-a-cell-to-stop-editing-in-excel-interop) was suggested as a previous answer, but the question and solutions are in C#, whereas I required a solution in Python. The problems are similar, but I believe the solution I found in Python is simpler anyway.

Comment: If a cell is in editing mode, pretty much all operations fail. Perhaps you could just select an arbitrary cell like "A1" and get out of the editing mode.
[Although, if you are programmatically changing a cell, I have not seen the cell the edit mode issue]

Comment: I tried selecting another cell, but that operation also fails when a cell is in editing mode. I want to make it so that only common fields are available on the Tk window, but more obscure fields can be accessed directly by using the Show button. I may just have to learn to deal with it, or find a non-programming work around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force a cell to stop editing in Excel interop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482935/how-can-i-force-a-cell-to-stop-editing-in-excel-interop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an effective solution. By checking the Application.Ready attribute you can determine if the excel file is in edit mode. Unfortunately, if the file is in edit mode, this still throws an error. I was able to work around by using a try statement to query, and catching the pywintypes.com_error exception.

I simply edited my code by adding a new function to check the status:

```
from pywintypes import com_error

def isReady(XL):
    try: return XL.Ready
    except com_error: return False

def buttonShow(XL):
    if isReady(XL):
        XL.Visible ^= 1
```

This seems to work. Now, if the excel application is still in edit mode, the button simply does nothing. If the excel application is not in edit mode, it works as expected and toggles the visibility.