# Error loading Office.dll COMException: 'Errorloading type library/DLL'

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, com, office-interop

I have a working Excel COM library and I am trying to use the following method to determine if excel is in edit mode

```
public bool IsEditMode(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp)
    {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464196/workaround-to-see-if-excel-is-in-cell-edit-mode-in-net
        //xlApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
        var bars = xlApp.Application.CommandBars;
        var commandBar = bars["Worksheet Menu Bar"];
        var menu = commandBar.FindControl(
                   1, //the type of item to look for
                   18, //the item to look for
                   Type.Missing, //the tag property (in this case missing)
                   Type.Missing, //the visible property (in this case missing)
                   true);
        if (menu != null)
        {
            // Check if "New" menu item is enabled or not.
            if (!menu.Enabled)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When my code hits xlApp.Application.CommandBars; I get the following exception.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))'
```

I believe the issue is because I am referencing the wrong version of the office.dll. Either it is targeting the wrong version of office or the wrong version of Visual Studio.

**My version numbers:**

- VS 2017 Community (15.8.6)
- Excel 2010 Office Standard 32-bit (14.0.7214.5000)

**References I have tried**

- Manually add reference to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\office\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\OFFICE.DLL
- Let visual studio add the reference automatically to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\office.dll
- VS Reference Manager -> COM -> Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library. (C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll)

All three of these references give me the same exception. Any ideas how to load this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with a typelib registration from a different version of Office. I ended up deleting registry entries for all versions of Office that were no longer installed.

These links gave me the info I needed to get it working.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac50fa41-8d47-4fa9-81a3-914f262676af/0x80029c4a-typeecantloadlibrary?forum=vsto

http://kb.palisade.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=528

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application" to dynamic? This should get around your issue with the library version. However you will lose intellisense for the object. Have a go just as a process of elimination firstly.

Comment: Also make sure the object you pass is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error since I upgraded from a 32 bit to 64 bit version of Office, which somehow resulted in `Win32` and `Win64` entries existing simultaneously in registry.

The solution that worked for me was deleting `Win32` entry from registry in

```xml
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9\0
```

since the `Data` was referring to invalid path

```xml
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
```

**Note:** Do keep a backup of the entry via `Export` just in case something goes wrong.