# Get value of Excel Cell still being edited

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I need to capture the value contained in any cell or cells that are selected in my Excel add in. I'm currently using ...ActiveWindow.Selection and get_Value() on that to get multiple cells selected at once and ...ActiveCell.Value to get a single cell being selected. My issue is that if you input a single value in a single cell and click the button, which captures the values, everything comes back null if that cell is still being edited (the cursor is still in the cell but you have input the value). Does anyone know of a way to capture this value? I can already see it being a source of confusion for my users when trying to enter a single value.

**Requested Clarification:**

```
var selectedCell = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.Value;
```

If I enter a value in this cell and immediately click the button, this value is null because the cell is in edit mode and not selected mode. To make it work I have to click off of the cell and then single click it to select. Think of the different states of a cell... if you double click it, it's in edit mode. If you click once, it is selected. I want the value of a cell that is still in edit mode.

Comment: When the user clicks the button Excel should validate its input that will become the cell value. So what you describe is pretty strange. Could you please provide more details, like some code.

Comment: See update... hopefully easier to understand

Comment: I've understood the issue but when you use on-sheet buttons you can't have this issue because clicking the button will exit edit mode and validate the data. It's why I was requesting more code. :) As for your issue I've never experienced it my users: they all knew they had to validate the data for it to be taken into account, so no need for code fix ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We struggled with the same issue in our VSTO add-in.  After doing a lot of research we concluded there is no way in the VSTO api to get the value of a cell that is still in edit mode.  We ended up hacking the following solution: whenever a button is pressed, it checks if Excel is in edit mode, and if it is, it pops up a dialog telling the user they must exit edit mode before pressing the button.

The code to check if you are in edit mode is:

```
public bool IsInEditMode()
{
    const int menuItemType = 1;
    const int newMenuId = 18;

    CommandBarControl newMenu =
        Application.CommandBars["Worksheet Menu Bar"].FindControl(menuItemType, newMenuId, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);

    return newMenu != null && !newMenu.Enabled;
}
```

You can see more info at: [How to tell if Excel Application is in cell-edit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221984/how-to-tell-if-excel-application-is-in-cell-edit-mode)

Comment: Thank you for this. Interesting that ActiveCell.Value would not be designed to pick up on this and return the correct value. Seems quite unnatural to have to click off of a cell and back to be able to capture what's inside.

Comment: Quite unnatural.  In fact there's a lot of unnatural phenomena in VSTO.  For example, you may want to consider using Value2 instead of Value, it matters if you will be dealing with date/time data.  Also I should mentioned that I haven't checked if the new version of VSTO for Office 2013 offers any way to get data from edit-mode cells.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this is the first excel add-in I've done. My target for this is Excel 2007 so that wouldn't do me much good anyway :) Trying to implement this now and I will mark as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following C# code to exit out of cell Edit mode. It works :

```
private void exitEditMode()
{
    if (!isExcelInteractive())
    {
        // get the current range
        Excel.Range r = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell;
        // bring Excel to the foreground, with focus
        // and issue keys to exit the cell
        xlBringToFront();
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Activate();
        SendKeys.Flush();
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        // now make sure the original cell is
        // selected…
        r.Select();
    }
}

private bool isExcelInteractive()
{
    try
    {
        // this line does nothing if Excel is not
        // in edit mode. However, trying to set
        // this property while Excel is in edit
        // cell mdoe will cause an exception
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive;
        return true; // no exception, ecel is 
        // interactive
    }
    catch
    {
        return false; // in edit mode
    }
}

private void xlBringToFront()
{
    SetForegroundWindow(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd);
}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
```

Comment: Does not work. Application.ActiveCell throws an exception, because excel is still in edit mode.