# Excel crashes when editing column

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I want to insert a new column when I press **F3**, my code works, but if I press **F3** while I'm editing some column - my Excel crashes. How can I solve this?

```
if (checkModifiers() && (checkKey(Keys.F3)))
{
    try 
    {
        Workbook wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
        Worksheet ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell;

        Range col = rng.EntireColumn;
        col.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, false);
        col.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;


    } 
    catch(Exception ex)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.EnableEvents = false;
```

and

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Interactive = false;
```

but it didn't help, or I used them in the wrong way.

[image]

Comment: Can you set a break point to see exactly which line causes it to crash?

Comment: @MattBurland it crashes at  col.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, false);

Answer (score 0):

You can't add columns while editing a cell. See the answers to [this SO question for code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221984/how-to-tell-if-excel-application-is-in-cell-edit-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1) that can test and let you abort if you press F3 accidentally while in a cell.