# Find out if excel is in edit mode from word-vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to find out from word if excel is in edit mode, I looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221984/how-to-tell-if-excel-application-is-in-cell-edit-mode) and tried to modify it, but it does not work if you have excel in edit mode, then run it, then exit edit mode rerun it still says it is edit mode:

[image]

```
   '*********************************************************
'********* define if we need to close excel after sub is done
'***********************************************************
Public Function setExcelObject(ByRef oXLApp As Object) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If oXLApp Is Nothing Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    setExcelObject = IsInEditMode(oXLApp)

End Function


Public Function IsInEditMode(ByRef exapp As Object) As Boolean
        If exapp.Interactive = False Then
            IsInEditMode = False
        Else
            On Error GoTo terminate
                exapp.Interactive = False
                exapp.Interactive = True

                IsInEditMode = False

        End If
        Exit Function

terminate:
         IsInEditMode = True
         Exit Function

    End Function
```

Note: It also takes awful long(15s) to figure out that it is in edit mode...

Comment: I don't think `Interactive property` is one to use here. Check [Application.Interactive Property from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-interactive-property-excel).

Comment: Can you remove `exapp.Interactive = False` and try again. The one after the `On Error GoTo terminate`?

Comment: Umm, I don't get it -- where's the code (in Word) that's producing the message ***"You are editing a cell in excel, stop doing that!"*** ...?  That's obviously not a message built-into Office, so it must be coming from something that you added.  Find that, and then you can _easily_ find **how** it's detecting that a cell is being edit.  Locating it could be as easy as going to a module and CTRL+F, choose to search in **entire project** and search for part of that phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code:

```
'**********************************************************************
'********* See if we can open excel, true is Yes we can work with excel
'**********************************************************************
Public Function setExcelObject(ByRef oXLApp As Object) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If oXLApp Is Nothing Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    setExcelObject = Not IsInEditMode(oXLApp)

    If setExcelObject = False Then Set oXLApp = Nothing

End Function

' *****************************************************************
' **************** Check if excel is in edit mode ****************
'*****************************************************************
Public Function IsInEditMode(ByRef exapp As Object) As Boolean
            On Error GoTo terminate
                exapp.Interactive = False
                exapp.Interactive = True

                IsInEditMode = False

        Exit Function
terminate:
         IsInEditMode = True
         Exit Function

    End Function

' *************************************************************
' *************** Check if excel is open, true, means we should not close excel after we are done.....
'*****************************************************************
Function ExcelOpen() As Boolean
    ExcelOpen = FindWindow("XLMAIN", vbNullString)
End Function
```

The above code I then call from several procedure like this:

```
' Get excel object
If Not FileHandling.setExcelObject(oXLApp) Then
    failMessage = "You are editing a cell in excel, stop doing that!"
    GoTo terminate
End If

' check if we need to close after
closeExcelMy = FileHandling.ExcelOpen

'See if we can open workbook
If Not FileHandling.GetWorkbook(wbName, oXLApp, xlApp) Then
    failMessage = "Failed to open workbook"
    GoTo terminate
End If

oXLApp.Visible = True
```